# How to allign grid of bootstrap 3 in center for extremely smalls screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I am trying to align column1 in center for extremely small screens. I have searched alot on internet. I have also used center-block class but it doesnt work.

Here is the pastebin link for reference: **http://pastebin.com/Kiv2anhy**

Since this is my first post on stack overflow any help to improve my questions will be considered.

Thank you!!

Comment: can you post some css as well or jsfiddle link

Comment: Ok sure let me paste a new code.

If you can see there are 3 blocks in this code:
Now i want that for small screens i.e for mobile only this block automatically align to center as it is. I want that left and right margin should be automatically adjust and there should be only 1 block in 1 row aligned center.

http://www.bootply.com/129041

Here is sample Code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to do this..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" id="column1">
    <img src="img/trending_sellers.png" class="img-responsive">

    <div class="rating-box">
      5.0
    </div>
    <p class="company-name no=padding no-margin">
      COMPANY NAME
    </p>
    <p class="small-logo">
      LOCATION, GOA
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/128953

Comment: I want to do something like this but not this way, if you can see if i use this method the whole column becomes so small. i want left and right margin to be automatically adjust but only for small screen. Sorry if i didnt explained you well. I have made one new code for your refernce.

Now i want that for small screens i.e for mobile only this block automatically align to center as it is. I want that left and right margin should be automatically adjust and there should be only 1 block in 1 row aligned center.

http://www.bootply.com/129041